# google charts annotations show right side of point

Tags: annotations, google-visualization

I am using google charts for plotting a graph

How can I show annotation of the point at right-hand-side of the point but it showing on the top of point
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHhQH.png

I want it like as follow
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUBcq.png

Please any one help me out

Comment: You can't move the position of the annotations, sorry.

Comment: Hi asgallant,Can I add image on top of it instead of text

Comment: No, the charts do not support adding images.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually change the position of the annotations, by using css tranform.

You should first get a handle to the anntation text, if you want to change all the text, then you can use the text tag name in css

```css
text {
    transform: translate(10px, 30px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to adjust annotations to the right by doing 2 things:

1) Entered some white spaces (\u00A0 is white space) and a long dash (—) on the left side of the desired annotation.

2) Added stem length of -3.

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Model');
 dataTable.addColumn('number', 'T');
 dataTable.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
 dataTable.addRows([
   ['ABC',30,'\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0 — X'],
   ['DEF',20,'\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0 — Y'],
   ['GHI',10,'\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0 — Z'],
 ]);

var options = {
   1: {annotations: {stem: {length: -3}}
};
```